# mergesorting 3 sub-arrays at once

Tags: java, arrays, merge, divide-and-conquer

I am making a program which implements the mergesort algorithm but instead of dividing each time in 2 parts it divides them in 3 parts each time and mergesorting them recursively. In case I confused you it is basically a mergesort but instead of mergesorting with 2 parts, you mergesort with 3 each time, sounds pretty fun huh? Well it definitely isn't.

Here is my implementation of mergesort:

```
public static void mergesort(int[] data) {
    int elements = data.length;
    int sizeLeft;
    int sizeCenter;
    int sizeRight;

    if (elements > 2) {

        if (elements % 3 == 0) {
            sizeLeft = elements / 3;
            sizeCenter = elements / 3;
            sizeRight = elements / 3;
        } else if (elements % 3 == 1) {
            sizeLeft = (elements / 3) + 1;
            sizeCenter = elements / 3;
            sizeRight = elements / 3;
        } else { //if (elements % 3 == 2)
            sizeLeft = (elements / 3) + 1;
            sizeCenter = elements / 3;
            sizeRight = (elements / 3) + 1;
        }

        int[] left = makeArray(data, 0, sizeLeft);
        int[] center = makeArray(data, sizeLeft, sizeCenter);
        int[] right = makeArray(data, sizeLeft + sizeCenter, sizeRight);

        mergesort(left);
        mergesort(center);
        mergesort(right);

        merge(data, left, center, right);
    }
}
```

Here is the the merge method:

```
public static void merge(int[] data, int[] left, int[] center, int[] right) {
    int[] temp = new int[left.length + center.length + right.length];
    int copiedTotal = 0;
    int copiedLeft = 0;
    int copiedCenter = 0;
    int copiedRight = 0;

    while ((copiedLeft < left.length)
            && (copiedCenter < center.length)
            && (copiedRight < right.length)) {

        if ((left[copiedLeft] < center[copiedCenter])
                && (left[copiedLeft] < right[copiedRight])) {

            temp[copiedTotal++] = left[(copiedLeft++)];
        } else if ((center[copiedCenter] < left[copiedLeft])
                && (center[copiedCenter] < right[copiedRight])) {
            temp[copiedTotal++] = center[copiedCenter++];
        } else {
            temp[copiedTotal++] = right[copiedRight++];
        }
    }

    while ((copiedLeft < left.length) && (copiedCenter < center.length)) {
        if (left[copiedLeft] < center[copiedCenter]) {
            temp[copiedTotal++] = left[copiedLeft++];
        } else{
            temp[copiedTotal++] = center[copiedCenter++];
        }
    }

    while ((copiedLeft < left.length) && (copiedRight < right.length)) {
        if (left[copiedLeft] < right[copiedRight]) {
            temp[copiedTotal++] = left[copiedLeft++];
        } else{
            temp[copiedTotal++] = right[copiedRight++];
        }
    }

    while ((copiedCenter < center.length) && (copiedRight < right.length)) {
        if (center[copiedCenter] < right[copiedRight]) {
            temp[copiedTotal++] = center[copiedCenter++];
        } else{
            temp[copiedTotal++] = right[copiedRight++];
        }
    }

    while (copiedLeft < left.length) {
        temp[copiedTotal++] = left[copiedLeft++];
    }

    while (copiedCenter < center.length) {
        temp[copiedTotal++] = center[copiedCenter++];
    }

    while (copiedRight < right.length) {
        temp[copiedTotal++] = right[copiedRight++];
    }
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, data, 0, left.length + center.length + right.length);
//        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//            if ((copiedRight >= right.length) && (copiedCenter >= center.length)) {
//                data[i] = left[copiedLeft];    // take from left
//                copiedLeft++;
//            } else if ((copiedRight >= right.length) && (copiedLeft >= left.length)) {
//                data[i] = center[copiedCenter];    // take from left
//                copiedCenter++;
//            } else if ((copiedCenter >= center.length) && (copiedLeft >= left.length)) {
//                data[i] = right[copiedRight];    // take from left
//                copiedRight++;
//            } else if ((copiedLeft < left.length
//                    && left[copiedLeft] <= right[copiedRight])
//                    && left[copiedLeft] <= center[copiedCenter]) {
//
//                data[i] = left[copiedLeft];    // take from left
//                copiedLeft++;
//
//            } else if ((copiedRight >= right.length) && (copiedLeft >= left.length)
//                    || (copiedCenter < center.length
//                    && center[copiedCenter] <= right[copiedRight])
//                    && center[copiedCenter] <= left[copiedLeft]) {
//
//                data[i] = center[copiedCenter];    // take from center
//                copiedCenter++;
//            } else {
//                data[i] = right[copiedRight];
//                copiedRight++;// take from center
//            }
//
//        }
    }
}
```

In the comments inside the merge method there is another merge method I tried to make but it didn't end well at all and things became way more complicated but I left it there for reference.

The problem is this doesn't work at all, for example if I have:

Input: 6 5 4 3 2 1

Then I'll have:

Output: [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]

I have honestly tried so hard for this and for 2 days straight, I found only two people even hearing about this kind of mergesort and after hours searching in Google I only found a similar question here (which was too complicated to understand) and another thread in wiki answers which was never answered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, of course I am not asking for a direct solution because I am trying to learn but tips and hints as well as what I have done wrong would greatly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gone through this with a debugger?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've gone through this with a debugger and it seems that the program just takes the pairs and reverses them that's why it's so confusing to me.

Comment: Also Vipar someone that is familiar with the mergesort algorithm would see that this is not just some big wall of code but it's a alteration for use with 3 subarrays instead of 2 and since I've spent so much time searching and looking through the debugger and writing code all over again I am obviously not looking for pitty and ready code here, my question was clear enough, read again I am just asking for tips

Comment: This is a good example of how the constant associated with the big-O of an algorithm makes certain techniques inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that when you have an 2 element array you dont do anything with it. You should sort it. If you take your example: [6,5,4,3,2,1], in the second step of recursion you have [2,1]; [4,3] and [6,5] and you merge them like that. If you would sort them first, you would obtained the right order. In order to sort them in merge function you should add:

```
if ((elements==2)&&(data[1]<data[0])){
 int aux = data[1];
 data[1] = data[0];
 data[0] = aux;
```

}

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

If you want to have a pure merge sort you can try (as I explained in the comment) to add the following piece of code:

```
if (elements==2){
 int[] center = [];
 int[] left = makeArray(data,0,1);
 int[] right =makeArray(data,1,1);

 mergesort(left); //you can call these methods or not, on a empty or 1 element array they dont have an effect
 mergesort(center);
 mergesort(right);

 merge(data, left, center, right); //it should work well when center is an empty array
```

}

**UPDATE 2**
You can refactor the code I shown so it looks beautiful. The basic idea is that you can have an empty array in Java and your merge function deals with it properly. Hope I made my point a bit clearer.

Comment: +1 I was wondering about `if (elements > 2) {` but I didn't quite put it together.

Comment: Yes I thought of that but the problem with this is that it seems like it is not entirely a mergesort but something like a mergesort of 2 parts with a mergesort of 3 parts, I was just not sure if that would qualify as a 3-part mergesort

Comment: If you want to have a pure merge-sort, you an try the following thing: when elements is 2, just make center = [], left=[data[0]] and right = [data[1]]. I will update the answer with the code.

Comment: about your update, you are then implying that I should have a second mergesort which is a regular mergesort (splitting in 2) and using that mergesort to sort the two left and right arrays?It's just that I can't have an empty array (the center one) in java, and even if I could wouldn't it create problems in the mergesort that I have created?

Comment: You can have an empty array in Java and from reading your merge function it should work well (think that the length of an empty array is 0). What I am saying is that you can call your merge sort function with the empty array. I will make a second update to the answer to be more clear.

Comment: yes I actually managed to do it with this command: int[] center = new int[]{};